# How to go to another activity if retrofit call is succeeded?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Iam newbie to Android.
I have a login page. if login is succeeded then go to another activity called (MainActivity) else show an error message.
My code is :

```
    private void submitlogin(){

    loginService = APIUtils.getLoginService();
    retrofit2.Call<EmployeeRolesModel> call = loginService.submitLogin("mail@test","123");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<EmployeeRolesModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<EmployeeRolesModel> call, Response<EmployeeRolesModel> response) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<EmployeeRolesModel> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

But when i got the following error

> error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous
> Callback>,Class) constructor
> Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable (argument mismatch;
> <anonymous Callback> cannot be converted to
> String) constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
> (argument mismatch; <anonymous Callback> cannot be
> converted to Context)

how I can move to another activity and pass data to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

Use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

you must send activity context to intent. this refer to something else if you want to know share full code of activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

private void submitlogin(){

```
loginService = APIUtils.getLoginService();
retrofit2.Call<EmployeeRolesModel> call = loginService.submitLogin("mail@test","123");

call.enqueue(new Callback<EmployeeRolesModel>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<EmployeeRolesModel> call, Response<EmployeeRolesModel> response) {
       //first way
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);

        //second way
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<EmployeeRolesModel> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

}